# FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect does not redirect immediately

Tags: jsf, redirect

An `Id` is passing in as a Url parameter. I try to make sure that the `id` is an number. If not redirect to the main page

```
if(facilityId != null){
    try{
        Long.parseLong(facilityId);
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        try {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("DisplayList.jsf");                    
        } catch (IOException ex) {}
    }
    facility = documentSBean.findFacilityById(Long.parseLong(facilityId));
    ...
}
```

so if I pass in an id like this

```
www....?facilityId=3?sdfasfda
```

I catch that `3?sdfasfda` is not a number, and get to the redirect statement, but it does not redirect right a way, it execute the next couple lines which try to convert `3?sdfasfda` to a Long, hence yield `NumberFormatException`. So is there a way to force redirect right away, or is there some other way to solve this problem. Wish that there is an `else` after a `catch` :D :D. The above codes are inside my `@PostConstruct init()` method

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, simply `return` from the method:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
   .getExternalContext().redirect("DisplayList.jsf");
return;
```

When you invoke `redirect(..)` the only thing that happens is that a special header (`Location`) is set in the response object. But the flow of the invoking method continues, unless you `return` from it after you call redirect.

Comment: ai ya. Why didnt I think of that. Thank you :D. Do you know why there is an delay on the redirect?

Comment: when you return there won't be delay.