# Spring Security + LDAP: session is cleared right after Login

Tags: jsf, authentication, primefaces, spring-security, ldap

I have a login page which uses Spring Security + LDAP. The authentication itself works correctly. The problem occurred after I changed the form from regular HTML to Primefaces/JSF tags. After the user gets authenticated, **the page doesn't redirect to the index page but after a second attempt**. For some reason the session is being cleared right after. I've read lots of posts and tutorials regarding login with JSF, and similar issues but so far none of them worked.

Here's some of my configuration:

**login.xhtml *BEFORE* Primefaces/JSF**

```
<form action='#{request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check' method='POST' id="loginForm">
...
</form>
```

**login.xhtml *AFTER* Primefaces/JSF**

```
<h:form id="loginForm">         
    <h:outputLabel for="j_username" value="User" /> 
    <p:inputText id="j_username" required="true" value="#{loginBean.username}"></p:inputText>

    <h:outputLabel for="j_password" value="Password" /> 
    <p:password id="j_password" required="true" value="#{loginBean.password}"></p:password>             

    <h:commandButton type="submit" id="loginButton" action="#{loginBean.doLogin}" value="LOGIN" />              
</h:form>
```

**securityContext.xml**

```
<security:http use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.xhtml" access="isAnonymous()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/index.xhtml" access="isAuthenticated()" />

    <security:form-login login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" 
                         login-page="/login.xhtml"          
                         authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"  
                         default-target-url="/index.xhtml"      
                         always-use-default-target="true" />
     ...
</security:http>
```

**LoginBean.java**

```
public String doLogin() throws IOException, ServletException {

       try {

           ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
           RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest)context.getRequest()).getRequestDispatcher("/j_spring_security_check");              
           dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest)context.getRequest(), (ServletResponse)context.getResponse());
           FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();

           return "/index?faces-redirect=true";          

       } 

       ...

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>loginBackingBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>my.project.jsf.beans.LoginBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>    
</managed-bean>
```

**Part of the stacktrace**

```
<SecurityContext is empty or anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession. >
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:435)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem was related to the redirection of the page after the login. I used the following line of code:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("inicio.xhtml");
```

I got the idea after reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102110/facescontext-getcurrentinstance-getexternalcontext-redirect-does-not-redirec/4102116#4102116.)

The **LoginBean.java** looks as follows:

```
public String doLogin() throws IOException, ServletException {

       try {

           ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
           RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest)context.getRequest()).getRequestDispatcher("/j_spring_security_check");              
           dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest)context.getRequest(), (ServletResponse)context.getResponse());
           FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
           FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("inicio.xhtml");   

           return;

       } 

       ...

}
```

Comment: you changed this in the doLogin() method?

Comment: Yes. Since you asked, I attached the final code in the above response.